# WordPress debug.log is not updating

Tags: permissions, debug

In my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); 
@ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

In my `php.ini` file, track errors is = Off

```
/wp-content/ permissions drwxrwx---

/wp-content/debug.log  permissions -rw-rw----
```

Where else can I look to get these errors to report?

Comment: What are you expecting to get logged?